# Which regression model should be preferred when multiple measures are taken for each subject?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have 50 subjects. Each subject has a tendency to fall, and I'm interested in the time it takes for me to come help them after they fall.

I want to see if the time it takes for me to help a subject after they fall varies whether it's night or day, and whether the subject falls frontwards or backwards.

I was thinking of using a multilinear regression to model the time it takes me to intervene as a function of day/night and frontwards/backwards.

The hick I see is that some of my subjects I've followed only in the day, others only in the night, and most both in the day and at night. Subject 1 might have fallen 10 times in the day, but only twice at night, over a period of observation of 3 days. Subject 2 might have fallen once in the day, but thrice at night, over a period of observation of 6 days. Subject 3 might have fallen once at night and only have been observed at night.

In such a scenario, I believe I need to take in count that my samples are dependent (since a same subject may fall during the day and at night). Hence, a multilinear regression would not be adequate. What are some methods to palliate this problem? Are there any univariate tests that can still be used in these circumstances?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct that a multivariable regression model is not qdequate here due to non-independence of measures within subjects. That is, measures within one subject are more likely to be similar to each other than to measures in other subjects. to account for these correlations, you can fit a model with random intercepts for subjects. Such a model is called a mixed effects model (because it contains fixed and random effects), or just a mixed model. In R, using daily standard syntax, this would look like:

```
intervention_time ~ day_night * front_back + (1 | subject)
```

This will estimate the *same fixed effects you would obtain for the model you were initially considering*, while also fitting random intercepts for subjects, which will account for the non-independence within subjects - in most software the random intercepts are assumed to follow a normal distribution.

Comment: Much appreciated, Robert. I had my suspicions that I'd need to use a mixed effects model.

I do have another question however, with regards to univariate analyses. Initially, I had planned to use wilcoxon tests to detect differences in intervention time in the day group and the night group. Then I realized I would need to take in consideration that my samples were dependent. However, Wilcoxon signed rank tests did not seem appropriate either, since I had differing numbers of measures for each group. Is there a way to perform univariate analyses with this data? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of the univariate analyses ?  The estimates from the mixed model should tell you about differences day/night and front/back, along with the interaction between them, while accounting for repeated measures.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking I would make subgroups -- intervention times in the day for instance -- and test whether intervention time varied according to front/back. I wanted to focus particularly on intervention times in the day, and then particularly on intervention time at night. However, I assume this would not be necessary because, as you said, the mixed model will take in count the interaction between day/night and front/back. Is this correct?
Also, are the assumptions for a mixed model the same as for a multilinear model? Thanks Robert, I'm new to this, and your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: I think the mixed model can answer all those questions. The assumptions are similar though independence is relaxed because that's why we use mixed models. The random effects are assumed to be normally distributed, but models are quite robust to departures from that.

Comment: I may not have been very clear in my previous comment. Let me offer you an example.

Let's say that intervention times are significantly longer for front falls rather than back falls. For some reason, I'd be more enclined to believe that intervention times are longer for front falls than back falls only during the day and that the difference in insignificant during the night. I'd like to analyze the day group of intervention times for differences between front/back, then analyze the night group in the same manner. Is this possible? Is this already taken care of in a mixed model?

Comment: My bad, you answered so quickly that I didn't have the chance to rectify my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, from what you said, it is. Try fitting the model and see. If you have problems interpreting the output you can ask a new question about that. But one concern that just crossed my mind is: is there any causal relation between the 2 explanatory variables ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. You're right, if I have another question, I'll ask it afterwards. I don't want to flood this discussion too much

The reason I gave the example is because, when I first began this project, I had (mistakenly) done univariate analyses in such a manner, and found that intervention time for front falls was longer than back falls during the day, but not during the night. Other than that, there was no logical causal relation I could find between these 2 variables.

For my personal knowledge, if there was a causal relationship between them, how should I go about this problem?

Comment: If there was a causal relation between them then one of them would be a mediator and should not be in the model at all.

Comment: @bagels Does this answer the question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not please let us know why